# How to get only the visible elements in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get only the visible elements present in HTML by using jQuery. But the problem is, it is also selecting the elements with "visibility:hidden".

```js
$("p:visible").each(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  console.log(input);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Paragraph1 content goes here</p>
<p>Paragraph2 content goes here</p>
<p id="myParagraph1" style="display:none;">Some text</p>
<p id="myParagraph2" style="visibility:hidden;">Some text</p>
<p id="myParagraph3" style="opacity:0;">Some text</p>
```

Here is an external link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/udhayakumar/newc91hm/

So, how to get the elements with both `display:none`, `visibility:hidden`, `opacity:0`, etc., Also, if an elements' parent is hidden in one of the above ways, that also should be considered as hidden as it is not going to visible in the page.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**:visible**](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.
>
> Elements with **visibility: hidden** or **opacity: 0** are considered **visible**, since they still consume space in the layout.

`visiblity: hidden` does not actually hide the elements from the *DOM*, the elements are in the *DOM* occupying space, but those cannot be seen. Unlike the elements which are `display: none`.

If you inspect the last paragraph https://jsfiddle.net/udhayakumar/newc91hm/ you'll see that it is `:visible`(*according to the above rules*).

**Solution**

We can use the elements `visibility` and `opacity` to check if the element is actually visible. No need to check for `display` property in the code below, as `:visible` will check for it.

```js
// Use :visible here to filter elements that are display:none
$('p:visible').each(function() {
  if ($(this).css('visibility') !== 'hidden' && $(this).css('opacity') != 0) {
    // visible elements
    console.log($(this).text());
  } else {
    // Element is actually invisible
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Paragraph1 content goes here</p>
<p>Paragraph2 content goes here</p>
<p id="myParagraph1" style="display:none;">Some text 1</p>
<p id="myParagraph2" style="visibility:hidden;">Some text 2</p>
<p id="myParagraph2" style="opacity:0;">Some text 3</p>
```

Comment: Not sure what your point is here.  Elements that are `display:none` or `opacity:0` are still in the DOM and will still be returned by a query.

Comment: @Archer I mean that are there in DOM but cannot be seen

Comment: Okay, I think I just misread what you're saying and took it a different way.  Are you not going to suggest a solution then, rather than just explain what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered to be visible, since they still consume space in the layout. During animations that hide an element, the element is considered to be visible until the end of the animation.
>   Refference jquery: https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

You can control it in another way:

```
$("p:visible").each(function () {
    if($(this).css('visibility') == "hidden") {
        console.log($(this));
    }
    var input = $(this);
    console.log(input);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use filter() to get the elements you really need.

https://jsfiddle.net/newc91hm/7/

```
var visible = $('p:visible').filter(function() {
    return !($(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden' || $(this).css('display') == 'none');
});

visible.each(function() {
    console.log($(this).html()); 
});
```

I hope it helps!

**UPDATE**
Not getting elements with opacity = 0

https://jsfiddle.net/newc91hm/13/

```
var visible = $('p:visible').filter(function () {
    return !($(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden' || $(this).css('display') == 'none' || $(this).css('opacity') == 0 ); 
});

visible.each(function () {
    console.log($(this).html()); });
```

Comment: `display: none` check in `filter` is not required as `:visible` will filter it already

Comment: Actually this one won't work for opacity:0, See this, https://jsfiddle.net/newc91hm/7/

Comment: Doesn't work with `opacity: 0`. Check here https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/newc91hm/8/

Answer (score 1):

You could write a jQuery plugin called `$.fn.isVisible` to determine if an element is visible by your standards.

```js
// jQuery plugin to check for element visibility.
$.fn.isVisible = function() {
  return this.not(':hidden') &&
         this.css('visibility') !== 'hidden' &&
         this.css('opacity') != 0;
}

$(function() {
  // Filter each paragraph that is visible.
  $('p').filter(function() {
    return $(this).isVisible();
  }).each(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    console.log(item);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Paragraph1 content goes here</p>
<p>Paragraph2 content goes here</p>
<p id="myParagraph1" style="display:none;">Some text</p>
<p id="myParagraph2" style="visibility:hidden;">Some text</p>
<p id="myParagraph3" style="opacity:0;">Some text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this as starting point. This does not account hidden parent elements, but you could adapt this to parents.

```
if ($elem.is(":visible") || $elem.css("visibility") == "visible" || $elem.css("opacity") == 1) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I can have some elements with `opacity: 0.5`. This doesn't mean it is invisible

Comment: Just change the check to `$elem.css("opacity") > 0`